# Email Summary using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

My intention with this code is to send an email summary of total reports sent in a day and send me a summary of this every day.These reports are stored in a database  The code works just fine but I need to add to functions to it:

1. Subject includes the date and total reports I sent every day
2. Within the body, I want to include total unfinished reports that are sent and total reports are sent.

   ```
       Program Prog = new Program();
       bool flag = Prog.SendMail();

       if (flag)
       {
           Console.Write("Success!");
       }
       Console.Read(); 
   }
       public bool SendMail()
       {
       MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
           Msg.To.Add("Email");
           Msg.From = new MailAddress("Email");//Mail account 
           Msg.Subject = "FLS Reports Sent "; // o Subject = Reports Sent – 
            {Date} – {Total Reports Sent}
           Msg.SubjectEncoding =System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
           Msg.IsBodyHtml =false; // Interim reports sent –  total unfinished 
                            reports that are sent and total reports are sent

           Msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

           SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient();
           Client.Credentials = new 
           System.Net.NetworkCredential("","Password");
           Client.Host = "smtp.qq.com";
           Object userstate = Msg;
           try
           {
               Client.SendAsync(Msg, userstate);
               return true;
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
               return false;
           }

       }
   ```

This is the connection string to my database

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=
             (localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=FLS_DB;
             Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;");
        try
        {

            SqlCommand Mycmd = con.CreateCommand();
            Mycmd.CommandText = (" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Services where  
            ServiceType= 1 OR ServiceType= 2");
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = Mycmd.ExecuteReader();
            do
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Service Type = " + reader[0]);
                }


            } while (reader.NextResult());
            {
                reader.Close();

            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

My question is how to includes the date and the total reports I sent every day within the subject in the email? Also how to include the total number of the unfinished and the completed reports within the body of my email?

Comment: what does the full method signature look like and the initial call look like in regards to partial code you have posted. what you are doing is not difficult however you may want to pass in a List<T> along with using the string.Join() function to format the contents you need to show all relevant code.. for example are the reports from Sql query..? is there a list of completed and uncompleted reports..please provide more information

Comment: I didn't do the sql query! However, do I need to include the to count the reports based on the Date?

Comment: You make very little sense, and with no effort to populate the body we are clueless as to the input data, how to adapt your subject, and even less incentive to do so. What have you tried to get the subject and body populated with the, let's say, dynamic data?

Comment: Can't understand what you are saying.. please edit the question, take time to formulate the question in to something more meaningful as well as show examples of all relevant code that you have thus far, as it pertains to your issue and where you are getting stuck

Comment: I have updated my question I hope I explained myself enough. Apologies for not explaining the intention of the question as I am still new in the C# programming and still learning :)